# AutoComplete with service and Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I've been struggling with getting all these components to work correctly, but when I get to the js it cannot find the TextBox control on the Student page.

The MasterPage ScriptManager:

```
<body>
<form id="MainForm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/AutoComplete.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Masterpage ContentPlaceHolder:

```
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderStudent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Student (child) page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderStudent" runat="server" >
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="StudentSearchPanel" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Inherit">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Search by student ID:
        <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="StudentIDSearchTextBox" runat="server" OnTextChanged="StudentIDSearchTextBox_TextChanged" Wrap="False" MaxLength="6" ClientIDMode="Static"  ViewStateMode="Inherit"></asp:TextBox>                 
        <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="StudentIDEntryError" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Text="Please enter a 6-digit student ID number."></asp:Label>
        <br />                        
        Or, begin typing student last name:
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="StudentNameSearchTextBox" runat="server" 
            CssClass="StudentNameSearch"
            ViewStateMode="Inherit"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Autocomplete Extender on the Student page:

```
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="StudentNameSearchTextBox_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="StudentNameSearchTextBox" 
            ServicePath="~/Scripts/AutoComplete.asmx"
            ServiceMethod="GetStudents"
            OnClientItemSelected="onStudentSelected" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
            CompletionSetCount="30" 
            UseContextKey="True" 
            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" 
            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" >
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

The AutoComplete.asmx is working, so I won't add that code. When I begin typing a student last name, I do get a json response, something like the following (altered to protect student data). I took this from FireBug:

```
{"d":["{\"First\":\"Lisaaa, Abby E.\",\"Second\":\"610999\"}","{\"First\":\"Lisbbb, Bobby P.\",\"Second\":\"151999\"}","{\"First\":\"Lisccc, Cathy M.\",\"Second\":\"739999\"}","{\"First\":\"Lisddd, David L.\",\"Second\":\"496999\"}","{\"First\":\"Liseee, Emily C.\",\"Second\":\"701999\"}","{\"First\":\"Lisfff, Frank G.\",\"Second\":\"623999\"}"]}
```

The problem, when I get to OnClientItemSelected="onStudentSelected" in GetStudentJson.js:

```
function onStudentSelected(sender, e) {
    var selectedStudent = eval("(" + e._value + ")");
    var StudentIdTextbox = document.getElementById('<%=ContentPlaceHolderStudent_StudentIDSearchTextBox.ClientID %>');

    StudentIdTextbox.innerText = selectedStudent;
    __doPostBack(StudentIdTextbox, "");
}
```

I get an error StudentIdTextbox is Null. I've tried adding all levels of placeholders by going to ViewSource to figure out how to find that box and give it the value of the student id, but to no avail. In fact, here is what it looks like:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderStudent$StudentIDSearchTextBox" type="text" maxlength="6" id="StudentIDSearchTextBox" />
```

Any advice??

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered that by problem lies in page lifecycle. Instead of referencing the script in the master page, I moved the script itself to the child page. Now, 'FindControl' is looking for a control that actually exists.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onStudentSelected(sender, e) {
        var selectedStudent = eval("(" + e._value + ")");
        var txtId = document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderStudent").FindControl("StudentSearchPanel").FindControl("StudentIDSearchTextBox").ClientID %>');
        txtId.value = selectedStudent;
    }
</script>
```

I was simply trying to find that control too soon.